# Are there any compatibility issues with Macros between Excel 2013 and 2016

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003, excel-2016

We have a user with an old 97-2003 Excel document with macros in, which they were using and running in 2013 without issue.

We have now upgraded to 2016 over the weekend, and when running the first macro in the workbook, cells that would normally show us a value, now show #REF!

Oddly, if we correct some of the references manually after the macro has run, then run the macro again, it does not have the same issue the second time around.

We are wondering if there are any changes in 2016 that might cause macros to behave in this way?

The first macro we are running is below:

```
Sub Update()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' Macro recorded 28/06/2007 by PETER WILSON
''
'
    Sheets("DCodes2").Select
    Range("C4").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("D23").Select
    Sheets("Sales Inv").Select
    Range("a2").Select
    Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Range("K5").Select
    Sheets("Invoices").Select
    Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Sheets("Job Costs").Select
    ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=-1
    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=6
    Range("N2:T2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N2:T284")
    Range("N2:T284").Select
    Range("N3").Select
    Range("J28").Select
    Sheets("Job Costs").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-1
    Range("N2:T2").Select
    ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=-2
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=9
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1
    Range("N2:T2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("N3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Daybook").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    Sheets("Job Costs").Select
    Range("N2:U2").Select
    Sheets("Summary").Select
    Range("I8").Select


'
End Sub
```

I am not clear on what the macro is supposed to be doing, so I am hesitant to go through and try to manually correct for the user in case I get something wrong, and I don't know enough about Visual Basic to determine what the above code is doing at each step.

Comment: "*I am not clear on what the macro is supposed to be doing*" How can we help if even *you* don't know what the code is doing? The code looks like it is worth to completely re-write it (looks like a mess of bad practices), but therefore you need to know what it should do first.

Comment: Because the macro was recorded over 10 years ago and the majority of us in IT and the end users who are using the report were not even with the company at that time. The user who recorded the macro is no longer with the business, so we can't ask them what the intention behind the macro is. The end users can tell us what fields they expect to be adjusted by the macro and have obviously highlighted errors, but what I mean by my statement is, I don't know HOW the macro is going about achieving its goal (i.e the actual code).

Comment: I understand your situation, but I see no chance to find an issue like that here. The code doesn't do anything spectacular, just one copy paste action, one autofill action (probably copy a formula down) and refreshing some query tables. That's it. But it's almost impossible to say what's going wrong here outgoing from just that piece of code you showed (it looks messy because it was recorded but I see nothing wrong with it). This might be the wrong place to ask such a question. Alternatively you need to hire someone who can check the whole file including formulas and query tables for you.

Comment: I would suggest checking the code against the Excel worksheets. Do the sheet names mentioned still exist? Do the ranges mentioned have data in them etc.Alternatively use debug to view code execution line by line to see where possible errors might occur.

Comment: All the data seems ok, and all references and formulas are valid, until the macro is run. Manually correcting what the macro breaks returns the correct data, and further runs of the macro (even after data changes) don't exhibit the same issues. The report ran fine in 2013 on a Friday, and then after upgrading to 2016, the exact same file exhibits these problems on the Monday. For now, the manual corrections seem to be sufficient for this report, I am just worried we have more hidden away that will have the same problems.

Comment: The list of changed features from Office 2013 to Office 2016 is at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt715497(v=office.16).aspx

Comment: Thanks for that. Doesn't look to be anything related to VBA or Macros, so guess it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some of the original code was recorded. This (below) appears to give the same functionality, removing extraneous and unnecessary code. (but I can't see the original sheets of course so treat this cautiously)

```
Sub EquivalentFunctIonality
Dim qt as QueryTable
Dim ws as Worksheet
For each ws in Worksheets
For Each qt in ws.querytables
qt.refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
Next qt
next ws
With Worksheets("Job Costs")
.Range("N2:T2").Copy .range(Range("N3"),.range("n3").End(xlDown))
End With
End Sub
```

See if this still gives errors.

Answer (score 0):

At this time I have not been able to find any change to 2016 that could be related to this issue.

I have just made manual corrections to the invalid references generated by the first run of the Macro, and allowed it to re-run (apparently successfully every subsequent time).

I have asked the end user to continually monitor the data in the workbook to ensure it is accurate, and will tackle any future workbooks with the same kind of issue in a similar way.